# How do I pass parameters with whitespaces to bash through subprocess?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a Python script that calls another shell script -

```
arg1 = "-a"
arg2 = "-b"
arg3 = "Some String"

argList = ["script.sh", arg1, arg2, arg3]
subprocess.call(argList)
```

When I run the script, `arg3` gets split to `"Some"` and `"String"` and is passed as two separate arguments.

How can I overcome this to pass `"Some String"` as a single argument?

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I was calling another function internally in the called script by passing the arguments as $1, $2, $3, .. etc. When I should've quoted the arguments that might have whitespaces like $1, $2, "$3" .. etc. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Use: `argList = ["sh", "script.sh", arg1, arg2, arg3]`

Comment: Tried including "sh" as first argument. Still the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import subprocess

arg1 = "-a"
arg2 = "-b"
arg3 = "Some String"

argList = ["sh", "script.sh", arg1, arg2, arg3]

subprocess.call(argList)
```

and inside `script.sh`

```
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

Make sure `"$@"` is quoted to avoid word splitting inside your shell script.

This will output:

```
-a
-b
Some String
```

Comment: This is what I did initially. The output I get is

`-a
-b
Some
String`

Each one is a separate argument (4). Also, I'm using ZSH, do you think that's causing this? EDIT: Removed ZSH, issue persists.

Comment: @entropy.maximum: Can you show your shell script where you're printing arguments?

Comment: I'm using "printf '%s\n' "$@" to print. Also I'm running MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Fixed. I was calling another function internally by passing the arguments as $1, $2, $3, .. etc. When I should've quoted the arguments that might have whitespaces like $1, $2, "$3" .. etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes,

```
arg3 = "\"Some String\""
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood the question. I want to pass the string as a single argument, bash interprets it as two arguments. Also, I'm using ZSH, is that an issue?

Edit: Removed ZSH. Issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import shlex, subprocess
args=shlex.split('script.sh -a -b "Some String"')
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more an extended comment than an answer.

Your code works fine in my Debian 9.3

```
$ cat sc.sh
#!/bin/sh
# Above line is mandatory - otherwise python returns error of unkonwn format
echo "arg1=$1"
echo "arg2=$2"
echo "arg3=$3"
echo "arg4=$4"

$ chmod +x sc.sh

$ pwd
/home/gv

$ cat test.py
import subprocess
arg1 = "-a"
arg2 = "-b"
arg3 = "some string"

arglist = ["/home/gv/sc.sh", arg1, arg2, arg3]
subprocess.call(arglist)

$ python test.py
arg1=-a
arg2=-b
arg3=some string
arg4=
```

PS : In my system python 2.17.14 is installed and bash 4.4.12

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake.
Fixed. I was calling another function internally by passing the arguments as $1, $2, $3, .. etc. When I should've quoted the arguments that might have whitespaces like $1, $2, "$3" .. etc. Thanks!